# fancybox gallery with voting

Tags: php, fancybox, gallery, voting

I have a fancybox gallery that is working perfectly but when I do a submit for voting instead of processing the form it goes to the next image

The fancybox script

```
$(".fancybox-button").fancybox({
        prevEffect      : 'fade',
        nextEffect      : 'fade',
        closeBtn        : false,
        helpers     : { 
            title   : { type : 'inside' },
            buttons : {}
        }
    });
```

The HTML page

```
<div  class="showContestant"><a class="fancybox-button" rel="fancybox-button" href="viewDetail.php?id=1" title="Fine Gal One">
<img src="images/pix1.jpg" width="100"  /></a></div>
        <div  class="showContestant"><a class="fancybox-button" rel="fancybox-button" href="viewDetail.php?id=4" title="Fine Gal two">
<img src="images/pix4.jpg" width="100"  /></a></div>
        <div  class="showContestant"><a class="fancybox-button" rel="fancybox-button" href="viewDetail.php?id=2" title="Fine asdfasfasf asfasfasfsadf Gal three">
<img src="images/pix2.jpg" width="100"  /></a></div>
```

The PHP page called

```
<? if (isset($_REQUEST['cid'])) { echo 'posted';} else{?>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <table width="500" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <td align="center"><img src="images/pix<?=$_REQUEST['id'];?>.jpg" width="400" height="400" /><input name="cid" id="cid" type="hidden" value="<?=$_REQUEST['id'];?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>My Picture Description: i am looking great in my red top!!!<br />
        Vote this Contestant;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="submit" name="Vote" id="Vote" value="Vote Me!!!" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
<? } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this API options

```
arrows: false,
closeClick: false,
```

.

Comment: why you don't provide a link with a sample of the issue? We could help you better.

Comment: www.wearsitbest.com/viewcontestants.php

Comment: When you click on vote me ...instead of posting the form...it moves to the next pix

Comment: the problem you have is that you are using API options for fancybox v.2.x BUT you are actually loading fancybox v.1.3.4. Upgrade both, you version of jQuery and Fancybox, then your code should work just fine

Comment: thanks i have upgraded to jquery 1.7 and fancybox 2.0...i now get page cannot be loaded????

Comment: i think my browser was cached...wen i tried another browser..it worked fine but closes the fancybox on click of submit button....even though i have upgraded ...i still cant process the form....it just closes the fancybox...

Secondly i noticed that with the upgraded version...the login and sign in popups which used to adjust to extend its heights when u select register or sign no more adjusts....